# jQuery: children count = 0 and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a jQuery that gets a list of elements from a server, appends it to an element, and then loops in the newly appended elements to transform them (make them jEditable).

I'm having trouble with the loop. The appending works alright, so I have a list of elements like :

```
<div id="innerModal">
    <label id="exampleTitle">Title :</label>
    <label id="exampleField" class="ftext">Value</label>
</div>
```

Then I try to loop in:

```
function makeListEditable(element, type){
    //I checked here that the element sent is well '#innerModal'
    alert($(element).children().length);
    $(element).children().each(function() {

        if( $( this ).is( 'ftext' ) ){
            makeEditable( $( this ), type, '', '' );
        }
    });
}
```

The alert prints "0".

Where does that issue come from? How can I fix it?

Edit : Here's the call of makeListEditable :

```
getFormOnElement(//Gets the form and appends it
    "getorganisationeditable/"+curOId,
                        "#innerModal"
    );
    makeListEditable('#innerModal');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How/when do you call `makeListEditable`? What is `element`?  Are you sure it's `#innerModal` and that it has children at that moment? Are you having multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: I call makeListEditable right after I append the values on the element. The argument `element` simply represents the element that contains a list I want to make editable.

Comment: You must be having another div with same ID

Comment: Well, you have to provide some more information (and a demo!), because what you posted works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/H9yk3/. So the important missing parts are how you create the elements and how you call that function. Regarding your edit: That's basically what I'm doing as well and it works. Hence the problem is somewhere else. Still not enough information. We can only help you if we are able to *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: The elements are appended in an ajax function. I updated the post with more detail on how I call the functions.

Comment: So `getFormOnElement` makes an Ajax request? Then `makeListEditable` will be executed before the Ajax request finishes (if it is not synchronous). Call `makeListEditable` inside the `success` callback *after* the elements have been added.

Comment: @Gabriel Theron - That `getFormOnElement`, does it use AJAX to get the data, or do you just generate it there and then on the client side?

Comment: Actually I just realized that the asynchronous request wouldn't have the rest to wait for it to finish. Thanks for helping me sorting that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ajax is asynchronous, it will not wait till elements are appended and execute makeEditable. Since ajax might not necessarily have completed, the element has no children. Move makeEditable to ajax call's success callback

Comment: That's what I just realized. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not at all. Mark as answered if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

`ftext` is a class and needs 'dot' `.is(".ftext")`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that mistake ^^ That was not the origin of the problem, but it always helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add an other allert like:

```
alert($(element).text());
```

or

```
alert($(element).html());
```

so you can know if your selector work fine.